# Is there a way to make pg_dump ignore errors instead of stopping?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm running a pg_dump of my postgres 9.4 DB and occassionally it'll hit an error if some other process has an exclusive lock on a table.  Is there a way for the pg_dump to just ignore that table and proceed with the rest of the database instead of just stopping in its tracks?

Comment: I don't think so.  `pg_dump` is designed to produce consistent dumps (terms apply).  If you did what you ask for, you'd miss data here and there in a completely unpredictable manner.

Comment: The question is why would you want such a behavior ? What would be the idea of having a incomplete backup ?

Comment: I'd rather it skip over any error tables, report them, then I can manually stop any processes that were taking a lock one table at a time to make a complete backup.  If I have 100 tables it doesn't make sense to stop all processes for a couple hours just to prevent a couple tables from having locks.

Comment: If you skip those tables, or add those problematic tables later to your backup, you will have an incoherent backup. Which is as good as no backup at all. If those tables can not be backed up, you need to take the proper steps to ensure a complete backup next time. If your tables are really really independant (I have some doubts), then ok, you could do without coherence. You could script your own backup routine that pg_dumps one table at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is missing from pg_dump and the right solution would be to enhance it by adding a flag with something like `--ignore-errors`, the comments miss the point that backing up some tables is better than none.
In a scenario where you only want to restore some tables this would be helpful.

There are few options using which you can implement a workaround:

1. Use the parameter below to reduce timeout to 10 sec, log the table and dynamically exclude that table from a new pg_dump command.
   `--lock-wait-timeout=timeout`
   `--exclude-table=table`
2. If you have a standby DB, use that to do your backups and you will have lesser chance of this issue happening.
3. If the issue is due to some unlogged stage tables, you can use the parameter below to ignore them ( I have not tested this so not 100% sure)
   `--no-unlogged-table-data`
4. Write a wrapper script and backup each schema or table, this way if the failure happens you will miss one schema or table, you will have to make sure to implement a similar wrapper for restore as doing it by hand would be problematic, also this would not be consistent at a DB level.